# Where do I need to put the UI initialization code in an IntelliJ Idea plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin for IntelliJ Idea, which puts a little button into the status bar.

AFAIK the code for this must look like this:

```
final StatusBar statusBar = WindowManager.getInstance().getStatusBar(project);
final StatusBarWidget widget = new WordCounterWidget();
statusBar.addWidget(widget);
```

[WordCounterWidget](https://github.com/fdrollig/wordcounter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fdrollig/wordcounter/WordCounterWidget.java) is the button I want to place into the status bar.

I tried to put it

- into an [action](https://github.com/fdrollig/wordcounter/blob/master/src/main/java/HelloAction.java) that is called, when I select a particular menu item and
- into the constructor of a [project service](https://github.com/fdrollig/wordcounter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fdrollig/wordcounter/impl/WordCounterServiceImpl.java).

None of this brought the expected result -- the button is not shown.

Is the above code for inserting a button (or anything else that can display text and is clickable) correct? If yes, where should I put it so that it's executed whenever a project is opened, re-opened, or created (the status bar widget should be visible all the time when there is a project open in Idea)?

The code is [here](https://github.com/fdrollig/wordcounter).

**Update 1:** Tried to change the code of [WordCounterServiceImpl](https://github.com/fdrollig/wordcounter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fdrollig/wordcounter/impl/WordCounterServiceImpl.java) to

```
public class WordCounterServiceImpl implements WordCounterService {
    private final Project project;
    public WordCounterServiceImpl(final Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Override
    public void projectOpened() {
        final StatusBar statusBar = WindowManager.getInstance().getStatusBar(project);
        final StatusBarWidget widget = new WordCounterWidget();
        statusBar.addWidget(widget);
    }
}
```

The button is still not shown.

Answer (score 2):

`com.intellij.openapi.components.ProjectComponent#projectOpened`

See:  https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_components.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but with no results (see update 1).

Comment: then you are doing it wrong. ProjectComponent is not a service - it has special xml declaration.